# Declaring an awk function in bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I have an awk script which is called by:

```
awk -f myawkfile.awk arguments
```

The awk script is called into my bash script using the same mentioned call.

Can I, instead of calling the awk script declare it as a function in my bash
script. I thought it would be easy by writing an `awk` in front and back
ticking the whole code, then to assign a function name to call it at will.
Somehow it doesnt do the trick.

I am trying to do this because I don't want my script to have dependency on another script.
And I am not the one who wrote the `awk` script. It takes a file as input , does some
stuff and gives back the modified file which is used in my script.

Comment: ***Why*** don't you want your script to have dependency on another script? I'd prefer to stick to one language per script file. It makes testing, reading and maintaining it ***much*** easier!

Comment: Yes ! you are right but running the script in a temporary folder makes the dependency a liabililty  .

Comment: Why not install the awk script somewhere in your `${PATH}`?

Comment: @Johnsyweb That will do it for us and that is what we generally do with our other scripts :) but  as for this one , our client demanded the script to do some tests on thier versions .I wanted to make it a single script taking portablity into consideration :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using [heredoc notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) one can write something like this

```
#!/bin/bash

awk_program=$(cat << 'EOF'
    /* your awk script goes here */
EOF
)

# ...

# run awk script
awk "$awk_program" arguments

# ...
```

Comment: Work great ! I never knew this trick :( Thanks a ton mate ! Saved me a lot of time !

Comment: Why use the heredoc?  Just do: `awk_program='put script here'`

Comment: @WilliamPursell because the script which is asked about and which was removed from the question contains more than 20 lines. Inlining will make it unreadable and unmaintainable (this may not be needed, but it's better to preserve such possibility).

Comment: @WilliamPursell additionally heredocs allow not to bother about escaping and to embed script as it is, which is useful in case of complicated ones.

Comment: The heredoc will fail if the script contains an unmatched `)` or the heredoc delimiter.  Using single quotes will fail if the script contains single quotes.  Pick your poison!  Using single quotes is more idiomatic.

Comment: Yeah, all has it advantages and disadvantages. The heredoc demiliter is easy to change, so it's probably lesser evil that single quotes. But I can't understand why heredoc should fail on unmatched `)`, can you please explain? It works in command line, though I didn't try embedding scripts with unmatched `)`.

Comment: I haven't tested many shells, so this may be shell specific, but in bash an unbalanced `)` closes the `$()` and the shell then attempts to parse the text between the ')' and the EOF as commands.

Comment: I didn't get I used `$(...)` at first, thanks for the explanation. Now I'm just for fun tried [this](http://ideone.com/g18cr). Seems like it should work for all possible symbols, which may be useful, if it's true.

Comment: @xaizek Any reason why this fails in solaris bash ? It tries to read into the declared function without the call being executed ! Any ideas ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand you. How's that? Does variable contain whole heredoc if you print it with `echo`? If it's echoed, then it heredoc works fine and bash configuration or different awk version could result in not working script. I didn't use Solaris, does it have `awk` linked to `gawk`?

Comment: @xaizek Yes , the awk is linked to the GNU one . It is not giving any problems with linux but with solaris ! I will include my whole awk function once I get a reply from you side .

Comment: @Geekasaur did you try to run the same scripts without heredoc on Solaris? I don't think it's the reason, since it's from POSIX standard and should work the same on all POSIX compliant systems.

Comment: @xaizek I have tried but always complains of unmatched quotes ! I have now included my whole awk function to the post . I cant seem to figure out the problem :(

Comment: @Geekasaur did you copy and paste the snippet? If yes, then the problem should be in the last line `EOF )`. `EOF` shouldn't be followed by anything, move closing brace to a new line like in my example.

Comment: @xaizek Yes , but the closing paranthesis is on the next line after `EOF`in my original code . But I am not sure about the parenthesis when I ran the code on my solaris machine at work . May be someone while modifying the script might have given a lift to the parenthesis .That is yet to confirm .I will let you know the results tomorrow . Did you try the code on your GNU machine ? It remove c/c++ style comments . Apart from the `)` do you find anything GNU specific in the code ? and thanks a lot for your time :)

Comment: @Geekasaur The end of snippet seems to have bad formatting, some code is commented out, so check if this is OK on your Solaris machine. I can see all code printed correctly with all comments. **But** how do you pass it to awk? Using `awk $awk_function ...` or `awk "$awk_function" ...`? The first variant is incorrect since it will cause pattern substitution (a star here), maybe this is why you don't see C-style comments.

Comment: @xaizek Yes ! That was it , I removed the comments in the awk function and it works just fine :) The Linux machine ran the same function code with comments included and gave the expected output. The solaris bash somehow got confused with the quotes included in the comments and read it as a part of the code ! Thank you for your help :) I really appreciate it .

Comment: @xaizek +1's for some of your other answers ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just write the awk script in a function:

```
#!/bin/sh -e

foo() { awk '{print $2}' "$@"; }
foo a b                         # Print the 2nd column from files a and b
printf 'a b c\nd e f\n' | foo   # print 'b\ne\n'
```

Note that the awk standard seems ambiguous on the behavior if the empty string is passed as an argument, but the shell guarantees that `"$@"` expands to zero fields rather than the empty string, so it's only an issue if you invoke `foo` with an empty argument.

Comment: I am not able to declare my awk script as suggested by you !